# Unit Testing Angular + Browserify + Gulp and Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, gulp, browserify

I'm having an angular project bundled with browserify using Gulp. Here is the tree

```
|--app
  |--src
    --js
      -main.js
      -otherFiles.js
  |--spec
    --mainspec.js <-- jasmin spec file
|--public
   --js
     --main.js
```

I'm having a gulp file which takes my source, main.js file, and browserifies it along with a `gulp-jasmine` tasks

```
gulp.task('js', function() {
   return gulp.src('src/js/main.js')
    .pipe(browserify({}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js'));
});

gulp.task('specs', function () {
return gulp.src('spec/*.js')
    .pipe(jasmine());
});
```

Along with some watch tasks etc.

Now, in my mainspec.js file, angular is not recognized, considering my test code:

```
describe("An Angular App", function() {
   it("should actually have angular defined", function() {
     expect(angular).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

And I'm getting an `ReferenceError: angular is not defined` error on terminal. I tried to `require('angular');` on the first line but with no luck, getting a new error `ReferenceError: window is not defined`. I know there is something wrong with the setup and the test file not being able to reach the browserified files, but I can't just figure out the solution.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define all aspects in your config file

```
function getKarmaConfig(environment) {
    return {
        frameworks   : ['jasmine'],
        files        : [
            // Angular + translate specified for build order
                    environment + '/js/jquery.min.js',
                    environment + '/js/angular.js',
                    environment + '/js/angular-translate.min.js',
                    environment + '/js/**/*.js',
            'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
            'test/unit/**/*.js'
        ],
        exclude      : [
        ],
        browsers     : ['PhantomJS'],
        reporters    : ['dots', 'junit','coverage'],
        junitReporter: {
            outputFile: 'test-results.xml'
        },
        preprocessors : {
              'prod/js/*.js': ['coverage']
        },
        coverageReporter:{
              type: 'html',
              dir: 'coverage'
        }
    };
};
```

and define a gulp test task like this

```
gulp.task('test', ['build_prod'], function () {
    var testKarma = getKarmaConfig(environment);
    testKarma.action = 'run';
    testKarma.browsers = ['PhantomJS'];
    return gulp.src('./fake')
            .pipe(karma(testKarma));
});
```

You just need to define src perfectly as per your structure. This will work :)

Comment: I'll give it a try and confirm. This also means I have to install karma?

Comment: Nothing works. Karma created a different conf file with different settings. I even installed coverage and PhantomJS but with no luck. The gulp task is erroneous.

Comment: You still see the same error? angular is not defined?

Comment: Yes, I installed karma-browserify and it worked. I had to make some changes to the config file and use a browserify transform (debowerify) in order to be able to require bower files into my test file. Thanks!

Comment: Were you able to get Istanbul coverage to work with this setup?